# Including node.js and karma for developing angular js app

Tags: javascript, node.js, angularjs, karma-runner

In Angular js, is it really needed to install node.js and karma while developing a sample app to learn angular? what they exactly do? please help me on this

Comment: Click on the tags you added at the bottom of your post. Then click the "info" tab.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No it's not mandatory to have node.js and karma install as long as you don't need to run unit tests.

You can directly import `angular.js` file in your page and start coding. :)